# trying to find a web service

Tags: php, web-services

i am trying to find a web service that allows a user to send a company name (or better still will return a list of all company names, thus allowing the user to select one) and then get the share price, this will then feed in to another api - yahoo currency converter to work out the price of the share

the issue i am having is that i cannot find a web service to get share info, google registration for theres does not seem to be working and as such i dont no what to do

i am to be coding this in php

if anyone could point me to a good web service i would appreciate it

thanks

edit : i did find this but am unsure if it is appropriate http://www.xignite.com/xGlobalQuotes.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 1):

How about:

http://www.sharepricewebservice.co.uk/

They get their data from Yahoo Finance, so I'm sure Yahoo would have an API somewhere.  This page may help: http://developer.yahoo.com/finance/

Comment: cool thanks, the thing is for my assignment we have to use more than 1 webservice, so if i use yahoo to get the data, then i cant use there currency converter, and seeign as i am having problems accessing the google api's i doubt i will be bale to use there currency converter

Comment: also, yahoo return a rss feed which i dont think i need.